# What kind of text may be wrapped within HTML code tags?

Tags: html, standards, w3c, semantic-markup

I would like to know what kind of text belongs to the HTML `<code>` element and what does not?

For example, I know that this is a good usage of HTML `<code>` tag:

```html
Use the <code>str()</code> function to convert the object into a string.
```

But I am not sure if these are good usages of the `<code>` tag:

```html
1. The list of users can be found at <code>/etc/passwd</code>.
2. We need to wait for <code>200 OK</code> response before the next step.
3. Enter the <code>ls</code> command to obtain a directory listing.
4. Compile the source code in <code>foo.c</code> to <code>foo.o</code>.
```

Is there a standards-document or a W3C guideline document or a similarly authoritative reference that precisely defines what elements may belong to the HTML `<code>` element and what may not?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the [`code` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/textlevel-semantics.html#the-code-element) (from HTML 5.2) is:

> The `code` element represents a fragment of computer code. This could be an XML element name, a file name, a computer program, or any other string that a computer would recognize.

This is what decides whether it’s allowed (i.e., semantic) to use the element or not. But you should also check if there is a more specific element available.

#### Reviewing your examples

> ```html
> Use the <code>str()</code> function to convert the object into a string.
> ```

This is fine.

> ```html
> The list of users can be found at <code>/etc/passwd</code>.
> ```

This is fine.

> ```html
> We need to wait for <code>200 OK</code> response before the next step.
> ```

You could consider using the [`samp` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/textlevel-semantics.html#the-samp-element) instead, which represents "sample or quoted output from another program or computing system".

> ```html
> Enter the <code>ls</code> command to obtain a directory listing.
> ```

You could consider using the [`kbd` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/textlevel-semantics.html#the-kbd-element) instead, which represents "user input (typically keyboard input, […])".

> ```html
> Compile the source code in <code>foo.c</code> to <code>foo.o</code>.
> ```

This is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are no good or bad usages of [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) tag.

To be more precise, HTML spec (and browsers, for that matter) is not opinionated on the syntax of a `<code>` tag's content. It does not check if it's valid code in any existing programming language.

Any [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) is **valid** from [HTML spec's](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element) point of view.
Any non-phrasing content is invalid.

---

The code tag is similar to `<pre>` tag and allows browsers (through their default stylesheets) and users to style content differently, based on the fact it is a different tag.

Many times, when code snippets, functions or method names (specific to programming) are used in other content, it is important (or at least desired) they are marked (and formatted) differently than normal text.
That is the intended purpose for which `<code>` tag was added to HTML.

This does not mean there's any mechanism in place stopping you from using it for any other purpose you may see fit, as long as it is fit for that purpose, given its limitation at only containing phrasing content.

Comment: Thanks for including the link to the official specification. Quoting from it, "The code element represents a fragment of computer code. This could be an XML element name, a file name, a computer program, or any other string that a computer would recognize." So it looks like all four example usages I provided in my question are consistent with the advice in the official specification.

Comment: @Lone, ref: *"represents a fragment of computer code"*: not exactly. In practice, from a technical point of view, neither the `<code>` tag, nor the browser interpreting it care if what is placed inside actually makes sense in any existing programming language. They only care if the content is **valid** (phrasing content) or **not valid** (any tag that's not phrasing context). Since text is phrasing content, it can be *any* text. The judgement on whether or not the content makes sense as code is yours, the browser is not equipped with any means of determining that.

Comment: Which means the following examples are just as "good" as each of yours: `<code>boo!</code>` or `<code>';'p[&(*&@!#</code>`, from the HTML spec's and browser's point of view. In fact, each of the snippets in this comment marked differently are `<code>` tags. They are valid and they are styled differently. And they serve their purpose: they mark portions of my message as `code`.

Comment: Just because a computer is not equipped to judge whether a piece of content is valid or not does not make it automatically valid or acceptable. For example, the contents of an alt attribute that is gobbledygook rather than equivalent content is not acceptable even though a computer cannot judge that.

Comment: @Alohci, technically speaking, considering the current standard, your example is both acceptable and valid. Of course, anyone is free to limit their own standard and redefine what they consider acceptable or valid. But the question was about current standard. Also note most, if not all programming languages accept comments, which can basically be any text. And `<code>`, by current definition, accepts it. As **it should**.